# Stress of the Wish Spell

Tags: dnd-5e, wish

In the Wish spell, related specifically to the stress you suffer from not replicating a spell of 8th level or lower, it states the following:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can’t be reduced or prevented in any way.

Does this apply to cantrips? They are spells, but are "level 0" for all other intents and purposes, so do I start 1d10 damage there and then amplify it when we go to level 1 (making it 2d10) and beyond?

I tended to not run the Wish spell when I was newer to DMing but this is my first campaign with it and my players recently hit this level so I'm looking for more clarification than anything else.

Comment: This is already answered here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108456/does-a-cantrip-count-as-a-spell-for-the-purpose-of-wishs-penalties?rq=1